# How to create Vertical Range Slider with No Thumb in CSS

Tags: css

I am new to CSS and trying to create a vertical slider with no thumb. This how far I got:

[image]

I would also like it to scroll all way to empty = 0; i.e., for the thumb to have zero height.

Here is my html and CSS. (It's only for Chrome atm since I need MIDI out but I would love to support the other browsers.)

```css
input[type="range"] { 
    margin: auto;
    -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 0; /* iOS */
/*     accent-color: #F50000; */
}

::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background:white;
}

/*
 * 1. Set to 0 width and remove border for a slider without a thumb
 * 2. Shadow is negative the full width of the input and has a spread 
 *    of the width of the input.
 */
::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 200px 0 200px rgba(30, 143, 255, 0.532), 0 0px 0 200px rgba(30, 143, 255, 0.33);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" value=50/>
```